# Point to specific value of an array

Tags: c, pointers, array-address

i have an array, `int* array`, with more than 10.000 int values, but i want to point to each 100 position, it means that I will have `int ** matrix`, where:
`matrix[i][j]`, I want `i` from my matrix to point to `array[i * 100]`, how can y substitute the address ? here is what I've done:

```
u_int8_t **matrix = (u_int8_t **)malloc(width * sizeof(u_int8_t *));

int width_cr = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i ++) {
    if (i % 100 == 0) {

        u_int8_t *position = matrix[width_cr];
        position = &array[i];
        width_cr ++;           

    }
}
```

the problem is that it points to the beginning of the array

Comment: [You should not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Unrelated, but you should change your loop increment to `i += 100` and remove the `if`.

Comment: @RichardChambers I'm pretty sure the OP just wants to build a 2d array that indexes into an existing 1d array.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this can be done with a union (assuming size is static).

Comment: yes i need to do 2d array, without to copy the whole bytes, i need just to point in matrix[i * 100][23], so if i is 3, it will point to 323 from the 1d array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the address of `array[i]` in `matrix[i / 100]`.

```
#define HOW_MUCH_NUMBERS 10000

[...]
{
  int array[HOW_MUCH_NUMBERS];
  int i = 0;
  int **matrix;

  matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * (HOW_MUCH_NUMBERS / 100));
  while (i < HOW_MUCH_NUMBERS)
  {
    matrix[i / 100] = &array[i];
    i += 100;
  }
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Can not say, should ask for those who are downvoting